# How do I create a bootable ISO with Windows 7 installation files?

Tags: boot, usb, lubuntu, windows-7, iso

I wanna install Windows 7, however I'm on Lubuntu 20.04 and I can't figure out how to convert my installation files into a bootable ISO.

I've tried Brasero to create the ISO and then I used woeusb to flash the ISO into my USB drive, however once it finishes, it shuts the computer off and when I try to boot from the USB, I'm stuck on a black screen with a blinking cursor.

I tried the same thing with a Windows 10 ISO and it worked with no issues.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Windows 7 can be used in UEFI boot mode, just not with UEFI Secure boot on. My old motherboard manual said "Windows" or "Other" as UEFI Secure boot setting. But also then said if using Windows 7 use "Other". Note that Windows 7 is obsolete and should not be connected to internet, if you must use it. Older Windows 7 ISO did not have /EFI/Boot folder & you had to copy boot files & rename to make it UEFI bootable.

Comment: [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) works with Windows versions 7 - 11, at least with official iso files from Microsoft. If you have problems, maybe there was an error when downloading the iso file. Please be aware also that Windows 7 was made for BIOS mode (alias CSM alias legacy mode) and it is tricky to make it work in UEFI mode. And as already stated by oldfred, Windows 7 has passed end of life so there are no security updates.